# How to tell if a function is in $L^1$ or in $L^2$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given a function, what properties do I need to satisfy to tell whether a function is in $L^{1}(R)$ and/or $L^{2}(R)$

For example, $\frac{sin(x)}{|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.

Do I just need to test if the integrals/square integrals are finite?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: First thing is to know if it's $L^2(\Bbb R)$, $L^2(0,1)$, $L^2(3,5)$, $L^2(1,+\infty)$; but yes, you need to estimate the integrals of the appropriate power of the **absolute value**.